# Games crashes to desktop with no error, artifacts and visual tear

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, windows-installer, visual-artifacts

I hope this is the correct stack exchange site.

4 days ago I upgraded my motherboard and cpu as well as new cpu cooler.

MSI Z170A TOMAHAWK -> MSI MAG Z490 TOMAHAWK
Intel i5 6600K -> Intel i5 10600K
Cpu Fan -> MSI MAG CORELIQUID 240R

and didn't change my gpu, ram and psu which are GEFORCE GTX 1070 GAMING 8G, Everest BTX-750-1 750W, 2x Kingston KHX2400C15/8.

I already clean installed Windows 10 Pro, updated BIOS, removed and reinstalled drivers for everything several times. Checked thermals and cpu doesn't go beyond 55-60, and gpu doesn't go beyond 75-80. I did every stress test and memtest and there has been no crashes or errors occurred. The main problem is whenever I try to play any games there are artifacts and screen tear happening, less than 10 minutes in the game, it crashes to desktop with no error. Tried Modernwarfare, Cold War, Battlefield5 and Witcher 3.

Only game it doesn't crash is minecraft and I host a 6 player server while playing on max settings. Most of the time these issues are bound to gpu but I literally took out a working gpu from one motherboard )very carefully and placed it to the other one. (When it didn't work, I took out and cleared the fins and put it back in). Also thermal values are really good. Only thing I know for sure is that my ram sticks are not supported by the motherboard but I don't think these problems occur because of that, if so I will gladly change the sticks but gpu is too much for my wallet. Is there any way for me to solve this, besides gaming I have zero problem, and I feel like it progressively gone worse while gaming, after hardware change I could play for maybe 10 minutes, now it crashes after like 2 minutes. I didn't hurt any of my components I am pretty sure, can the ram sticks not being compatible cause these problems ?

Comment: What is concerning to me is that when you say "crashing to the desktop".. it makes no sense to me.  So you have two scenarios.. either you have a device driver doing this.. which would make a blue screen.. or you have a user mode application catching the exception, eating it, and exiting.  The second is the likely answer.. but not against multiple games of different studios.. I AM an expert and you also have me confounded.  Perhaps you can give us more information.  Have you reviewed your windows logs?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think I figured out the problem. I lowered my gpu core clock by 100 MHz and set my temperature limit to 77 degrees with MSI Afterburner and it seems to fix the problem. I have been playing for over an hour and it didn't have any problems I mentioned previously. I feel like its a PSU and overall temperature problem. Not sure tho, so if you have any suggestions I am all ears.